# Splitting a string throws InvalidOperationException when hosting on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core

I wrote the following code:

```
private string makeMailContents(Klant klant, Mail mail)
{
    var builder = new BodyBuilder();
    var path = Path.Combine("wwwroot/trackers/track_open.png");
    var img = builder.LinkedResources.Add(path);
    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(mail.Content);
    string decoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
    string code;
    string final = "";
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[([^]]*)\]");

    img.ContentId = MimeUtils.GenerateMessageId();

    var splitContent = decoded.Split(' ');

    foreach(string word in splitContent) // this is line 265
    { 
            if (word.Contains('[') && word.Contains(']'))
            {
                try
                {
                    code = Regex.Match(word, @"\[([^]]*)\]").Groups[1].Value.ToLower();
                    switch (code)
                    {
                        case "voornaam":
                            final += regex.Replace(word, klant.vnaam) + ' ';
                            break;
                        case "achternaam":
                            final += regex.Replace(word, klant.anaam) + ' ';
                            break;
                        case "naam":
                            final += regex.Replace(word, klant.vnaam + ' ' + klant.anaam + ' ');
                            break;
                        case "onderwerp":
                            final += regex.Replace(word, mail.Onderwerp + ' ');
                            break;
                        case "datum":
                            final += regex.Replace(word, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ' ');
                            break;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    final += ex;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                final += word + ' ';
            }
    }
}
```

Whenever I run this code on my local machine and my test server it executes the code like it should without any exceptions.

But whenever I host this on my current live server it throws the following exception:

> InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements

And this exceptions keeps pointing towards the `splitContent` and it tells me that it doesn't contain elements. And yes, the `mail.Content` is filled with a valid `base64` string, I checked both with fiddler and postman.

Does anyone have the slightest clue of what's going on here? I'm also not sure if it's the IIS settings or somehow my code. I normally have a colleague who manages the IIS but he is on vacation right now. Can someone help me out with this?

This is the data the mail receives when called:

```
 {      
    "Onderwerp":"Dit is een test campagne",
    "afzender":1,
    "campagne":1,
    "Content":"PHA+RGl0IGlzIGVlbiB0ZXN0IG1hYXQ8L3A+Cg==",
    "docs":"['kamer2.jpg']",
    "template":null,
    "verzenddat":"8/17/18, 3:55 PM"
}
```

full exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Last[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass17_1`1.<CompileQueryCore>b__0(QueryContext qc)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Last[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at MailerAPI.Mailer.Sender.makeMailContents(Klant klant, Mail mail) in C:\Users\Hofkey\Source\Repos\MailerAPI\MailerAPI\Mailer\Sender.cs:line 265
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
   at MailerAPI.Mailer.Sender.<sendMessage>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Hofkey\Source\Repos\MailerAPI\MailerAPI\Mailer\Sender.cs:line 161
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MailerAPI.Controllers.MailController.<Post>d__13.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Hofkey\Source\Repos\MailerAPI\MailerAPI\Controllers\MailController.cs:line 96
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

The exception also gets thrown when I replace the model properties with just a plain string.

**UPDATE**
Whenever I run this code in my values controller to test the `decoded.split(' ')` it actually works. When I return the `decoded.split(' ')` I actually get an array of strings.

So now I know that the problem only occurs within the method, which is located in a Sender class and being called in the MailerController, and it also only occurs in the current server.

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that `decoded` doesn't contain any whitespaces. Have you checked this by adding a breakpoint?

Comment: @ViggoLundén: that's not it.  If you run `var res = test.Split(' ');` after `string test = "StringWithNoSpaces";` you end up with a one element array containing the original string.  It doesn't throw.

Comment: @Flydog57 that's right, I forgot about that. Then the only other explanation I can think of is that `mail.Content` is `null` or "".

Comment: If you search SO, the posts matching that error that show up all are the result of doing something like `collection.First()` on a non-null, but empty collection.

Comment: And if it were to be null it wouldn't lead anywhere closer to the answer because the main mystery is still there. Why does it work on my test server and local machine and NOT on my current server?

Comment: Can you share a full stacktrace - if possible, deploy the `.pdb` files on your server to get linenumbers?  What is happening in `// something`?

Comment: The foreach loops checks if a word contains certain characters and then replaces it with regex and the corresponding value from a model. E.G. [name] turns into YourName

Comment: The stacktrace shows **`Entity Framework`** related hints via eg. the namespace `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler`. I assume that the `klant` variable is an `Entity Framework` object and that it is being addressed within the `// something` block in a way that it causes `EF` to throw. Please show the `// something` block. Also add a `try/catch` within the `foreach` loop with some logging of the `klant` data, as it will probably be data related.

Comment: Agreed, the stack trace goes directly from `makeMailContents` to `Linq.Queryable.Last`, so it looks like the issue is in the `// something` making a call to `Last()` on an empty sequence.  Nothing in the posted code _appears_ to be able to do that.

Comment: Should the variable `regex` be `regReplace`, as its declaration is missing?

Comment: sorry, made a few changes in the mean time, but yes regReplace is regex

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve]. This is not all the code, and the code you show doesn't reproduce the issue you describe.

Comment: Can you share the method containing `MailController.cs:line 96` and all methods involved in `Sender.cs`? I would like to see any `EF Linq` statements being executed.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be making a call to `.Last()` at or through the code located at `C:\Users\Hofkey\Source\Repos\MailerAPI\MailerAPI\Mailer\Sender.cs:line 265`.

The Linq extension method `.Last()` demands that there is at least one item that it can grab. To work around this requirement, you have various options:

- use `.LastOrDefault()` accompanied with appropriate `null` handling, or
- before using `.Last()`, first check with `if (... .Any())` if it  is OK to call `.Last()`.

For further reference, see [LINQ Element Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/element-operations)